# File download in the button handler in extjs

Tags: button, extjs, onclick, download

I have to download a file in the click event of a button in extjs. The dialogue should ask whether to open or save the file. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable cross-browser way to do it is to:

1. Implement server side script that will send the file with Content-Disposition header
2. Create iframe element in JavaScript
3. Set this iframe src attribute to the URL that will activate script from step 1

Unfortunately, it's quite implementation specific so there's not much to say about Ext JS side of things. And it won't work with Ajax requests.